# Array is turning a into string

Tags: php

I am trying to show a list of the users friends, but it keeps telling me that

> Array to string conversion in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Root folder/messaging.php on line 40

and then it displays SELECT  username FROM users WHERE user-id=Array. The second part of the thing is supposed to convert the user-id into usernames.

```
include 'databaseconn.php';
if (isset($_POST['friends'])) {
  $sql = "SELECT user_two FROM friends WHERE user_one=" . $_SESSION['user-id'] ."";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  foreach ($result as $friend) {
     $sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE user-id=" . [$friend] . "";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     echo "<button><p>$result</p></button>";
  }
}
```

Comment: You do not seem to have actually FETCHed a row from the resultset. Check the manual page for the answer https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: what is a manual page

Comment: The [PHP User Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), useful to all, be they beginners or experienced developers

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.